# Solving Simultaneous Equations - Hill Cipher

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I have searched but an unable to find any examples like what I am faced with.

Plaintext = SOLVED
CipherText = GEZXDS
2x2 encryption matrix

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
  11 & 21 \\
  4 & 3
 \end{matrix}
\right)*\left(
\begin{matrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
 \end{matrix}
\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
  25 & 23 \\
  3 & 18
 \end{matrix}\right)
$$

with the result:
$$11a +21c \equiv 25 \text{(mod 26)}$$
$$4a + 3c \equiv 3 \text{(mod 26)}$$

and

$$11b + 21d \equiv 23 \text{(mod 26)}$$
$$4b + 3d \equiv 18 \text{(mod 26)}$$

I have found a solution.
solve for a:
$$11a + 21c = 25 (mod 26)$$
$$4a + 3c = 3 (mod 26)$$

-> (multiply second equation by 7) =

$$11a + 21c = 25 (mod 26)$$
$$28a + 21c = 21 (mod 26)$$

-> apply (mod26) where required and Subtract =

$$9a = 4 (mod 26)$$
9 inverse mod 26 = 3
$$a=3*4 =12$$

Solve for c:

$$11a = 132$$
$$2 + 21c = 25 (mod 26)$$
$$21c = 23$$
21 inverse = 5
$$c = 5*23 (mod 26)$$
$$c=11$$

and so on.

Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: Hey Ryan, what exactly are you trying to do? Just solve these systems of equations?

Comment: Trying to find the values for a,b,c,d (mod 26)

Comment: Have you tried throwing your systems into an augmented matrix and putting them into reduced row echelon form?

Comment: Haha I wish I understood what this is but it has not been covered in my course. I am looking into it now. As I have video lectures the example my teacher has done if left at this point and it is assumed knowledge that we should be able to solve this so I am not sure what method they are looking for.

Comment: I have the practise questions answers so I will edit the post to show them. I am just trying to figure out how they came to that answer

Comment: The questions has given plain text and cipher text and reqested us to find the encryption matrix.

Comment: SOLVED -> GEZXDS or 18,14,11,21,4,3 - > 6,4,25,23,3,18

Comment: is there a way to display a matrix on this site?

Comment: Yeah, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Comment: thanks editing to try to properly display the matrix now

Comment: Ryan, I took the liberty of adding the parens to the matrices and putting the displayed matrix equation on a single line. Do roll back, if you disagree with the changes.

Comment: Your matrix has determinant $-2$ which is not coprime to $26$. Therefore you will have multiple solutions (or no solutions). Looks like you need another (ciphertext,plaintext) pair to find the matrix. Mind you, the determinant is coprime to $13$, so you can invert it modulo $13$ and get the two solutions that way (or prove that none exist).

Comment: Here are my 3 Plaintext Ciphertext pairs. 18,14 -> 6,4 & 11,21 -> 25,23 & 4,3 - > 3,18. I can use any 2. My teacher chose 11,21 -> 25,23 & 4,3 - > 3,18 though did not explain why. I will try that

Comment: Pick a pair such that the determinant is not divisible by neither two nor thirteen (if such a pairt exists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing the question about multiplying by seven.

If you know that the congruence
$$
x\equiv y\pmod{26} \tag{1}
$$
is true, then you also know that the congruence
$$
7x\equiv 7y\pmod{26}\tag{2}
$$
is true. This is because the first congruence simply states that $x-y$ is divisible by
$26$. Consequently also $7(x-y)=7x-7y$ is divisible by $26$ which is exactly what the second congruence claims. In other words $(2)$ is a consequence of $(1)$, or
$(1)\implies (2)$. The logic will automatically flow in this direction and we could have used any integer in place of $7$ here. The real question is whether we can also go backwards? In other words, does $(2)\implies (1)$ or, can we deduce that $(1)$ is true if and only if $(2)$ is true.

To that end it is necessary that $7$ and $26$ are coprime. Simply stated this is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (=uniqueness of prime factorization of integers): multiplying an integer by seven will not make it divisible by $26$ unless it already is. The same conclusion can be reached by using a modular inverse of $7$. You have hopefully seen how that can be found (when it exists) using the extended Euclidean algorithm, so I simply make the observation that
$$
7\cdot15=105=1+4\cdot26\equiv1\pmod{26}.
$$
How does this help? Repeating the above logic we see that because $7\cdot15=105$ the congruence $(2)$ implies the congruence
$$
105x\equiv105y\pmod{26}\tag{3}.
$$
But on the left hand side of $(3)$ we have $105x\equiv x$ and on the right hand side we have $105y\equiv y$, because both $104x$ and $104y$ are divisible by $26$ for all integers $x,y$. Thus $(3)\implies(1)$, and we are done.

---

Addressing the question of finding the key matrix (the question was edited by the OP as it turned out that he had made an unlucky choice of two ciphertex/plaintext pairs)

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
  11 & 21 \\
  4 & 3
 \end{matrix}
\right)*\left(
\begin{matrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
 \end{matrix}
\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
  25 & 23 \\
  3 & 18
 \end{matrix}\right).
$$

You can solve this system of congruences any logical way you can/want. I show how to do it using the inverse matrix.  The general recipe for inverting a $2\times2$ matrix (hopefully you have seen this in linear algebra or elsewhere) is
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22}
 \end{matrix}\right)^{-1}
=\frac1{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}}
\left(\begin{matrix}
  a_{22} & -a_{12} \\
  -a_{21} & a_{11}
 \end{matrix}\right).\tag{4}
$$
Everything here makes sense in modulo $26$ arithmetic except possibly division by the determinant. As above, we can divide by an integer modulo $26$ by multiplying with the modular inverse provided that the inverse exists, i.e. provided that the number we divide by is coprime to $26$.

The determinant of your matrix
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}
  11 & 21 \\
  4 & 3
 \end{matrix}
\right)
$$
is $\det A=33-84=-51\equiv-51+2\cdot26=1\pmod{26},$ which is, of course, equal to its own inverse. Therefore
$$
A^{-1}=\left(\begin{matrix}
  11 & 21 \\
  4 & 3
 \end{matrix}
\right)^{-1}=\frac11\left(\begin{matrix}
  3 & -21 \\
  -4 & 11
 \end{matrix}
\right)\equiv
\left(\begin{matrix}
  3 & 5 \\
  22 & 11
 \end{matrix}
\right)\pmod{26},
$$
as $-21\equiv5\pmod{26}$ et cetera. We can then solve the matrix equation $(4)$ simply by multiplying it by $A^{-1}$ from the left hand side. The result is
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
 \end{matrix}
\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
  3 & 5 \\
  22 & 11
 \end{matrix}
\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
  25 & 23 \\
  3 & 18
 \end{matrix}\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
  90 & 159 \\
  583 & 704
 \end{matrix}\right)
\equiv
\left(\begin{matrix}
  12 & 3 \\
  11 & 2
 \end{matrix}\right)\pmod{26}.
$$

Leaving it to you to check all the calculations and the verification that this key matrix is compatible with the third plaintext/ciphertext pair that you have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Clears everything up!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $3$ is invertible mod $26$.

Comment: so 3 * 9 = 1 (mod 26) therefore inverse is 9

Comment: I don't know what to do with that information

Comment: Use it in the first equation to find $c$ in terms of $a$.
Then substitute into the second equation.

Comment: I am trying to do this now. though I am not sure how i would use in in the first equation. Wouldn't this give me 4a + 3c = 9 (mod 26) which I am still unable to answer? forgive my stupidity, math is not really a strong point of mine.

Comment: Why would you get $4a+3c\equiv9\pmod{26}$? You can't just magically change a 3 into a 9. What you do is multiply both sides of the congruence by 9. Then solve for $c$. Then plug into 2nd congruence.